# Switching between NVidia and AMD graphics in runtime

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics

So I have a laptop with AMD/ATI motherboard and NVidia discrete card.

Is there a way to switch between those with a press of a button perhaps? It seems that only NVidia can work with external HDMI whereas it also drains the battery at an alarming rate.

`prime-select` and nvidia settings program offers to switch between NVidia and Intel, which is funny since I have an AMD/ATI system. Neither seems to allow to do so instantly.

Comment: No, not yet possible in most systems. A reboot is necessary.

Comment: It's quite sad to have this hardware but no way to employ it.